# Android "cannot resolve symbol R" after deleting built in activity

Tags: android, r.java-file

My project was compiling until I added the built in Login activity and then deleted it despite the warning(not safe because there are associated ...) when I deleted it. I also deleted the associated login activity xml file. Now my project cannot compile and I am getting "cannot resolve symbol R" in every reference of R.id....Android studio also opens the v23\Values-v23.xml as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- From: file:/usr/local/google/buildbot/repo_clients/https___googleplex-android.googlesource.com_a_platform_manifest.git/mnc-sdk-release/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v23/styles_base_text.xml -->
    <eat-comment/>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Button.Inverse" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse"/>
    <!-- From: file:/usr/local/google/buildbot/repo_clients/https___googleplex-android.googlesource.com_a_platform_manifest.git/mnc-sdk-release/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v23/themes_base.xml -->
    <eat-comment/>
    <style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat" parent="Base.V23.Theme.AppCompat"/>
    <style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V23.Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>
    <style name="Base.V23.Theme.AppCompat" parent="Base.V22.Theme.AppCompat">
        <!-- We can use the platform drawable on v23+ -->
        <item name="actionBarItemBackground">?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground</item>

        <item name="controlBackground">@drawable/abc_control_background_material</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Base.V23.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V22.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- We can use the platform drawable on v23+ -->
        <item name="actionBarItemBackground">?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground</item>

        <item name="controlBackground">@drawable/abc_control_background_material</item>
    </style>
    <!-- From: file:/usr/local/google/buildbot/repo_clients/https___googleplex-android.googlesource.com_a_platform_manifest.git/mnc-sdk-release/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v23/styles_base.xml -->
    <eat-comment/>
    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored" parent="android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored"/>
</resources>
```

I did clean project, rebuild, Invalidate caches/Restart but none of them worked. I also checked to see if there is reference of the activity in my manifest that was added automatically but there is none. Are there associated files that are added automatically and that I need to delete manually? Even if I delete this file Android studio generates the same file when I clean my project.

Comment: Make copy and delete from your project  `v23\Values-v23.xml` file.

Comment: I did delete that file but it is being regenerated automatically after I added it and clean/rebuild my project.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved by changing my compileSDKVersion from 21 to 23 per [this thread](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183149). That did the trick, however I don't have a good explanation as to why.